# Sort Code, Account Number, but no account name

Tags: united-kingdom, money-transfer, online-banking, online-payment

I'm trying to pay money into an account. I have the Sort Code and Account Number, but no account name. I know the company that owns the account, but I'm sure they have MANY accounts. Can I put just put "XYZ company" as the account name?

Comment: Can you add any background to this? Explain why you're putting money into an account that's not yours?

Comment: I don't see how that information will add anything to the question. The company is a charity. I did some fundraising and I don't have the account name.

Comment: Background information often helps offer a bigger picture of the situation. As your question was posted, it's not personal finance, and likely to be closed as off-topic. One might ask why you are depositing anything and not simply mailing the charity a check. A country tag might help, too, as bank regulations are different around the world.

Comment: `Can I put just put "XYZ company" as the account name` Yes you can. If the sort code and account number are correct, it should be fine to go. For additional safety, transfer £10 and then do the rest once confirmed by the other party.

Comment: New Anti-money laundering laws mean the answers here are wrong. Now the exact name must be used.

Answer (score 7):

To the best of my knowledge the UK's online banking systems look purely at the Sort Code and Account Number when routing transfers.  The name is not cross-checked to ensure it matches. This is why it's so easy to [misdirect transfers](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/finance/personalfinance/bank-accounts/11149121/I-lost-28000-mortgage-deposit-How-to-get-back-money-sent-to-the-wrong-bank-account.html) if you make an error entering the numbers and inadvertently enter the details for a valid account belonging to the wrong person.

So in your case so long as you're sure you have the correct account number and sort code it doesn't matter what you put in the name field - it'll end up in the account to which those numbers apply.  Of course you might as well put your "best guess" into the name field since it doesn't hurt, and in the event that something does go wrong it's backup evidence of your intentions.

Comment: Agreed. However, I would say to add your "best guess" as to the relevant name in the name field - it won't matter if it doesn't exactly match, but if you do end up with the wrong numbers and the money goes into Joe Bloggs' account instead, it will help your case with the bank to point out that you put "British Heart Foundation" (or whatever) on the name.

Comment: @Vicky Good point. I've edited to include something along those lines.

Comment: In the BACS world (the UK's automated credit and direct-debit system), and almost certainly the same for "Faster Payments" (the system usually used for one-off, online transfers) the account name would only be looked at if the sort-code/account-number didn't identify a real account. **Note**: Although misdirected transfers _can_ cause headaches (and make great headlines), sort-codes and account numbers feature a _degree_ of redundancy and checksum validation, so _many_ mistypings will either fail a validity test, or yield a non-existent account.